# How to put other activity in a tabhost?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie in android can anyone help me with my problem about TabHost? 
i have a Tab host and 3 class want i want is to put or call this activiy or class to TabHost. what I'm going to do. Here is my code in my Tab Host:

```
public class Tab extends Activity  {

    TabHost th;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab);

        Resources res = getResources();    

        th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);    
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("Settings", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_setting));
        th.addTab(specs);

        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("Battery Information",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_batteryinfo));
        th.addTab(specs);

        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("Help", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_help));
        th.addTab(specs);
    }
}
```

Where am i going to call those three class that i made?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the Intent as `Intent intent = new Intent(this, otherActivity.class);` and set this intent to `specs.setContent(intent);` [`Here`](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/11/17/tablayouttabhost-tutorial-for-android-reusing-layout/) is an Example for using Tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `TabActivity` in place of `Activity` when you are using Tabs. And also you don't need to find it by id.

So you should change your code as shown below,

```
public class Tab extends TabActivity{
    ...
    TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        ...
        setContentView(R.layout.tab);

        ...
        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables   
        tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost  
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab    
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab   

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity1.class);  
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab One").setIndicator("Tab One",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.first_tab)).setContent(intent); 
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity2.class);  
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab Two").setIndicator("Tab Two",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.second_tab)).setContent(intent); 
        tabHost.addTab(spec); 

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity3.class);  
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab Three").setIndicator("Tab Three",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.third_tab)).setContent(intent); 
        tabHost.addTab(spec); 

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); // set first tab selected when activity is first loaded
        ... 
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add all 3 activities too to your manifest file,i.e. Activity1.class,Activity2.class and Activity3.class.

Comment: when you are using `Activity`, you can use Tabs in `Activity`. the only thing you need is to find `TabHost` by `findViewById()` and then call method `tabHost.setup();`

Comment: Yup.i know that.but i was explaning the way i have given example of.

Comment: why is there an error when i call the TaskKiller.java in my tabhost? they are in the same package. here is the error :

 E/AndroidRuntime(6462): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Comment: Please post your logcat.and also provide the line for the number specified there that is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using ActivityGroup instead of Activity. Check the below link you will get an idea.

[Experience - Multiple Android Activities in a TabActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

I hope it may help you.

Comment: I do all of your recommendation but still i got an error. it always prompt me to force close the application. i didn't know what to do. my head is aching for this thing. :) 
what i what is to call TaskKiller.java that extends Activity and the function of this class is to kill all running application. is it possible to call this class? please help me thanks for the help.